# How to Execute Commands on Browser-based terminal IDE from a Markdown or Instructions manual

Tags: linux, terminal, theia, katacoda

I am looking to do a cool project like [Killercoda](https://killercoda.com/) for a kids learning group where I expose VMs via browser access using terminal access such as [code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server) IDE or [theia](https://theia-ide.org/) IDE (which killercoda uses). I am able to spin up the VMS using kubernetes pods and expose them via an ingress resource.

However, what I can't seem to implement or wrap my head around is how killercoda or [katacoda](https://www.katacoda.com/)(now deprecated) have instructions on the left side of the browser execute commands on the terminal access (as seen in the picture attached).

[image: Sample implementation of issuing instructions from the left to the terminal]

The closest I could get is a `markdown` configuration of where the instructions are coming from such as the below:

```
### Single line code blocks can be copied by default
`copy me`

### It can also be disabled
`copying disabled`{{}}

### Execute a command per click
`ls -lh`{{exec}}

### Send Ctrl+c before execute
Run a blocking command:
`sleep 1d`{{exec}}

End it and run another:
`whoami`{{exec interrupt}}
```

How are the `{{ exec }}` commands placeholders passed to the terminal session and get executed.

There also have an `index.json` on the steps to run/execute from the instructions manual and then bunch of `.md` files in the directory. An exmaple given is:

```json
{
  "title": "Lab 1",
  "description": "Everything Linux",
  "details": {
    "intro": {
      "text": "intro.md"
    },
    "steps": [
      {
        "text": "step1.md"
      },
      {
        "text": "step2.md"
      },
      {
        "text": "step3.md"
      }
    ],
    "finish": {
      "text": "finish.md"
    }
  },
  "backend": {
    "imageid": "ubuntu"
  }
}
```

I just need a guide such as the `tools` or `frameworks` or `resources` or `templates` or `languages` on how that is down (execute commands from instructions to the terminal session). I know the project is (was) open-source to some extent that is why I think there's the support out there.

My current project tools are:

- Django Rest framework (api)
- Vuejs (frontend)

Comment: Any help? Still got no comment on this

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. All that `Killercoda` and `Katacoda` are doing is using vagrant to create a VM and then make a rest API call from the `README` file to the VM. I don't think this is possible with a k8s pod.